# NUnit SetupFixture doesn't seem to work with version 3.11

Tags: c#, nunit

nunit 3.11
nunit3test adapter 3.12

Second class runs without problems, first one says there is no unit tests. Also if I have multiple tests in one method with multiple `[TestCase]` does the `[OneTimeSetup]` run for each test or is it one time per class/setupfixture?

```
[SetUpFixture]
public class UnitTests
{
    private string test = "not inialized";

    [OneTimeSetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        test = "initialized";
    }

    [OneTimeTearDown]
    public void Teardown()
    {

    }

    [TestCase]
    public void Test()
    {

        Assert.AreEqual(test, "initialized");
    }
}

[TestFixture]
public class UnitTests2
{
    private string test = "not inialized";

    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        test = "initialized";
    }



    [TearDown]
    public void Teardown()
    {

    }

    [Test]
    public void Test()
    {

        Assert.AreEqual(test, "initialized");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

SetUpFixtures do not contain tests. They are intended to perform one-time setup for the TestFixtures within the same namespace.

OneTimeSetUp methods in a TestFixture run one time for the fixture. Use a SetUp method if you want something to run before each test.

OneTimeSetUp methods in a SetUpFixture run one time for the entire namespace.

For all this stuff, you may want to consider spending some time with the documentation.